# How to compare the time in from the nearest scheduled time

Tags: php, mysql

can someone please help me how to fix this code. What I need is to let the current time compare it to the nearest saved schedule in the column "from"

because the current time is only comparing it to the first added schedule

code:

```
                <?php
            //Include the database configuration
            include 'config.php';
            //Get the data of the selected teacher
            $teacher = $dbconnect->prepare("SELECT * FROM time WHERE IMEI = ? AND NFC = ?");
            $teacher->bindValue(1,$_GET['IMEI']);
            $teacher->bindValue(2,$_GET['NFC']);
            $teacher->execute();
            //Get the data
            $time = $teacher->fetch();
            //Store the current time
            $current_time = new DateTime();
            //Placeholder variables
            $time_difference = 0;
            $remark = "";
            //If there is such a teacher let the teacher enter
            if(!empty($time))
            {   

                //Get the time difference
                $time_difference = round( (strtotime($current_time->format('H:i:s')) - strtotime($time['From'])) / 60 );
                //Check if the professor is late or not
                //If the time difference is negative he/she is early
                if($time_difference < 0)
                {
                    $remark = 'Sir why are you so early?';
                }
                //If the prof is on time which is 0 time difference or less than 15 minutes
                else if($time_difference == 0 || $time_difference < 15)
                {
                    $remark = "Sir it's a miracle you are on time";
                }
                //Oh come on why are you so late Sir?Porn marathon at night?
                else if($time_difference == 15 || $time_difference > 15)
                {
                    $remark = 'Sir why are you late?';
                }

                $time_in = $dbconnect->prepare("INSERT INTO time_in (teacher_id,name,NFC,IMEI,time_in,remarks) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                $time_in->bindValue(1,$time['teacher_id']);
                $time_in->bindValue(2,$time['name']);
                $time_in->bindValue(3,$time['NFC']);
                $time_in->bindValue(4,$time['IMEI']);
                $time_in->bindValue(5,$current_time->format('H:i:s'));
                $time_in->bindValue(6,$remark);
                $time_in->execute();
            }
            ?>
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>Welcome!</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h1>
                <?php
                //If there is such a teacher,welcome him/her
                if(!empty($time))
                {
                    echo 'Welcome '.$time['name'].'! Your NFC is '.$time['NFC'];
                    echo '</br>';
                    echo 'Time in at: '.$current_time->format('H:i:s');
                    //This is just a temporary display to show the time difference for testing.Kindly delete it later
                    echo '</br>';
                    echo 'Time difference: '.$time_difference;
                    //Display remark
                    echo '</br>';
                    echo 'Remark:'.$remark;
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'You are not registered.';
                }
                ?>
            </h1>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: What is `IMEI` and `NFC`? You should be able to use `now()` to compare the times to the current time.

Comment: The IMEI and NFC is fetched from the database once you typed the link http://localhost/test//time1.index.php.?IMEI=1234&NFC=1234 it has a corresponding schedule of time in the database. once the link is opened it will compare the current time to the scheduled time. but it only compares to the first schedule in the database

Comment: If you loop the `$teacher->fetch` you will get all records... or http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php but you should be able to do the logic in SQL.

Comment: https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=20882076839 here is the image of our database. it has 2 saved schedules. our code only compares the current time to the first added schedule.

Comment: oops sorry. here is the new link of the photo

https://www.dropbox.com/sc/4zmd5td1e4lp153/AACToHAcN3GnSL6vq5uZgHoYa

Comment: So you only get id `1`, correct? If so you need to fetch all records or loop the fetch. Fetch alone only gets the first record. Looping it continues the pull. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php